Pytest mock ring.redis decorator
Below is my class implementation:
class Person:
   def __init__(self, n):
     self.n = n
     self.foo = self.fun()

  @ring.redis(redis.RedisClient, coder="json")
  def fun(self):
     another_thirparty_class()
     # somebusiness logic here
  
  def bar(self):
     a = self.foo["a"]
     print(a+1)

Now I want to write the test case for bar() but it is failing. I have mocked all but seems like @ring.redis is creating problems:
@pytest.fixture
def mock_redis():
    return redis.StrictRedis(
        host="fake-host",
        port="fake-port",
        db="fake-db",
    )

@patch("path.myfile.redis")
@patch("path.myfile.another_thirparty_class")
def test_bar(mock_another_thirparty_class, mockredis):
  mockredis.return_value = mock_redis()
  p = Person("xyz")
  p.bar()

Even after mocking redis it is still going to redis and getting below error:
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to fake_host:1234. Name or service not known.

redis isn't a callable, so giving mockredis a return value doesn't really make sense. I think you want mockredis.RedisClient.return_value = mock_redis().

(If so, you should be able to patch redis.RedisClient directly.)

However, you need to patch these things before you import whatever module defines Person, because ring.redis gets called when the class Person is first defined, not when you instantiate Person.

@chepner can you please give an example on where and how to import ?
